# find button by ID or TAG

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a button programmatically and give it a ID and a Tag.

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setId(i);
button.setTag(anotherID);
```

i is a counter.

Now i want to change the background of this button, but i can't find it with

```
findViewByID(ID)
```

or

```
findViewWithTag(anotherID)
```

I use for ID and anotherID the values that i created the buttons with, but i only get NullPointerExceptions. I get no ids from a XML file, because i create the buttons programmatically. Did anybody know how i can handle this?

Comment: I think Where the `yourview` you added the button, then you should call `yourview.findViewByID(id)` to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

save your created element into a list like this

```
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
```

add your created button to the list

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setId(i);
button.setTag(anotherID);

buttons.add(button);
```

now you can get your created views over the list like this

```
for(Button b: buttons) {
     if(b.getId().equals(your_id_to_check)) {
         //DO WHAT YOU WANT
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would normally keep a reference to your programmatically created button. Never set Id manually. the R file is created at compille time not runtime so what your trying is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use tag for find id of controls, i am pasting code here..may this help to you.

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setTag(value);

int Qid = button.getTag();
```

Comment: This is what i also try, but i got problems to find the Tag again, findViewWithTag(anotherID) is what i try, but i dont get it to work

Answer (score 0):

First of all What you want to do? If you want to change the `Button` Background color after creating it dynamicaly then your code is fine but don't give ID to it. As because id is the Integer Value Generated by the file `R.java`.

Just See it and you will come to know:

So use below code:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.White);
```

Hope you got the point. If you have any issue then let me know.

Comment: Yes i want to change the button color after i create it. I got 20 buttons and the got a "state". I want to change the state of some one of them afer a event.

Comment: Which state you want to Change?

Comment: How you got the state ? Or you can define each button with different name and can able to change the Background color

Comment: the Button color shows the state -> green,red,white a service in the backgroud change the color

Comment: @Boe-Dev: Anyway i think you got the solution. Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my Soulution:

```
public static List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
public static List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

...

```
buttons.add(button);
ids.add(something.getInt(0));
```

...

```
public void changeButtonState(int res, int ID){ 
    int counter = 0;
    for(Integer i: ids){
        if(i==ID){
            Button b = buttons.get(counter);
            b.setBackgroundResource(res);
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

it works perfect for  my situation. The ids are some ids from the database, the are not sorted.