# How to get position of dynamically created view inside linear layout on click

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, viewgroup

I created a linear layout and adding dynamic views inside it, i want to get position of dynamic view inside linear layout when clicked, how can i do this

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how can i set tag

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890100/recognizing-a-button-from-a-dynamic-view  this will be helpful for adding tag for dynamic views

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but why not to use `indexOfChild` method of `ViewGroup` ?

```
private int getViewIndex (ViewGroup viewGroup, View view)
{
    return viewGroup.indexOfChild(view);
}
```