# How to select element by its tagName in android studio and not by id

Tags: java, android

Good day all, I am two weeks old learning Android studion.

How can I use `findViewByid` to select all element just like `jQuery` where you can use `$(button)` to select all button tag?

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ltA"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ltB"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"/>
```

Instead of having

```java
findViewById(R.id.ltA);
findViewById(R.id.ltB);
```

Can I have?

```java
findViewByTagName(R.id.Button);
```

Thank you as you help.

Comment: It [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783102/find-button-by-id-or-tag) the solution you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but ive tried using it but its not working as expeced..
I want to select all <button /> using just one findViewById to select all.